# Swagger Codegen 3 with Angular 15

Tags: angular, typescript, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm using Swagger Codegen 3.0.34, trying to change the angular version specifically to use Angular 15. I've created a config file which does work for generating interfaces and a few other options, but I can't seem to get it to change angular versions.

```
{
  "ngVersion": "15..."
}
```

The issues I'm having, and hoping will be fixed with a specified angular version are in the encoder, and a few model files.

Some of the generated models have a non-existent type of "modelObject"

And the endcoder file needs to have override added before the encode key and value

```
override encodeKey....
```

How do I set the angular version used by swagger codegen to 15, and will that solve this issue?

Here is the command I'm using for codegen.

```
java -jar C:/tools/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.34.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l typescript-angular -o C:/swagger-code-gen/3-6-23-eight -Dmodels=true  -DmodelDocs=false -DmodelTests=false -c C:/tools/angular-swagger-option.json
```

**UPDATE:**
I have figure the override issue with the encode value, by editing the template for typescript-angular and specifying my edited template with the -t flag

I am running into an issue where some of my generated models and APIs are trying to import objectModel from a file of the same name, but the file doesnt exist, nor does the model exist on my swagger

**UPDATE:**
This is fixed with using Swagger codegen version 3.0.41

Comment: Can you post the exact command you use to run the codegen?

Comment: I edited the question to include the command